# Do any browsers allow you to play embedded MIDI files with Mountain Lion?

Tags: browser, osx-mountain-lion, midi

I have always used Safari, but now can't play MIDI files embedded in webpages. Fine. I'll switch to another browser if necessary, as playing MIDI files is pretty important to me as I'm a musician.

But, so far, I've only tried Firefox, and this requires opening Quicktime in a separate window to play MIDI.

Can any browsers play files directly from webpages (eg. MIDI files at Wikipedia)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post this on **Ask Different**. Let me know if you want me to post it there instead...

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don't know where to post this answer but it's related to the unsuccessful embedding MIDI file on many websites or blogs. But we can still download it.

I have the same problem. I think the biggest problem isn't in the browser, but in MIDI itself. I also hope the browser can accept MIDI file embedded in blogs (except for special sites) but until now there has been no confirmed answer.

I try not to worry, there are other ways, and the most important thing is we can still download original MIDI files. MIDI is indeed beautiful but mysterious for me haha!

So I try made the simple player with simple codes, in a rectangular box with buttons to download original MIDI file and the score in PDF format. For audio just using hidden HTML5 audio player.

And that's all just decoration to differentiate between "MIDI player" with hidden HTML5 audio player, (in my blog,can compare the sound with the default HTML5 audio player below it), hopefully interesting.

But basically the sound is MIDI file processed by DAW then exported, and result is audio format like MP3 etc. which has MIDI sound. This is an example on my blog: https://blogngacak.blogspot.com/2023/06/penggunaan-vsti-mt-power-drum-kit-2.html. Sorry my English and hope this help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: We want your answer to be complete on this website. We don’t want a link to your blog. This question should have been migrated 9 years ago to the proper community

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm trying to help because this is a similar case. My blog is only the theme of software lessons and it is the personal blog, I'm not a pro like you, just a beginner.

Comment: If there any solution and it is confirmed through any media, of course I will not visit this post.